# Will a cross site XMLHTTPRequest ever re-use credentials?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, csrf, basic-authentication

There is an open source daemon that has a JSON API. This daemon forces the use of basic HTTP authentication. I'm considering submitting a PR to always send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to allow the API to be consumed by other webpages, but I want to ensure it doesn't present a security risk.

If a user is logged in to the API, I know AJAX requests from the same domain automatically get the HTTP `Authorization` header. From my tests, this is never the case if the request comes from another domain.

Is this how all browsers implement it and am I correct that a malicious site cannot perform a request to the API unless it knows your creds, and that it isn't possible (save for a browser exploit) to get the creds via JavaScript?

Comment: Is the Authorization header sent if you add it to the list of allowed headers? `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization`

Comment: Even with that enabled my browser won't send creds so I think it's safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't have the [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) response header set, it will not allow authorisation for API requests that read data (the request will still be made, although the response cannot be read by the other domain due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)).

You still should implement [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) protection for methods that have consequences - i.e. make changes to your system, that are not considered [safe](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). CSRF is where a malicious site could make a cross site request and then reuse user credentials from the browser.

I would also advise that rather than setting

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

you only set this header to allowed consumers of your API. For example, in an AJAX request the `Origin` header will be sent:

```
Origin: https://example.com
```

When you receive this request, you should check in your back-end DB that `https://example.com` is an authorised consumer. If so you would output this header instead:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com
```

This will prevent `evil.com` from being allowed to bypass the Same Origin Policy due to your CORS implementation. As said, in your tests as you are adding the `Authorization` header manually via JavaScript it doesn't appear to be cached by the browser, however all browsers are not created equally and taking these extra steps would be a good security precaution.

Comment: Yeah it looks like if I just allow the `Authorization` header I can manually set the header with JavaScript. No security issues that I've found.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add in CSRF protection anyway just in case browsers handle this differently.